# Site loads empty html but backend is accessible after database import

Tags: joomla-3.6

I recently tried to sync my live site with my dev site for some updates. I had a SQL error when trying to import the database via terminal `ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 39: Duplicate entry 'stats_siteurl' for key 'PRIMARY'`, so I dropped and recreated the database and everything seemed fine initially. However, now when I try to access the previously working URL for my dev site, I get empty html, just this `<!DOCTYPE html><title></title>` is loaded into the page. 
However, the admin page and all the content seems to be present on the back end, so I'm at a total loss as to what is happening here. Nothing is wrong with the live site so far as I can tell.

Comment: this doesn't seem to me like you something with the database, rather like you are loading an index.html document instead of the index.php - make sure you are forcing your server to load .php files first instead of .html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, an index.html file had gotten places in the root folder by accident (mistargetted rsync) and that was causing the blank html. [Blank front end](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=283982)
Seems to happen a bit.